# What is the best way to send reminders with mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a reminder for users that they needs a cut. The interval is based on the users settings.
I'm updating a timestamp every time a user schedules an appointment.

The `Users` schema looks like this:

```
Users:{
    reminder:{
        [BarberID1]:{
            interval:2, //in days
            lastScheduled:1609090071 // timestamp when the user has scheduled an a appointment last time
            }
        },
        [BarberID2]:{
            interval:2, //in days
            lastScheduled:1609090071 // timestamp when the user has scheduled an a appointment last time
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm fetching every `User` once a day with a cronjob, and checking each of them if I need to send a reminder notification.

I'm not sure that this solution is scalable, so I thought I'll make a question here.

Let's say that I have 100k users and each of them has at least 3 barbers.

Thanks!

P.S: I saw somewhere a possible solution with `mongoDB TTL` and `change streams`, but I don't want to delete the user after a reminder was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say without going into much detail : **that is pretty much the way you do it.** When it comes to iterate over all users (even if you have 100 k) you would be surprised how fast this operations can be, however "speed" is not really an issue here, so if this operation takes e.g. 20 seconds it still shouldn't be a problem. There is no one waiting and looking at the screen and waiting for a result, it's a background task.

> How you determine which users needs to be notified can vary of course. A need for scalability depends, e.g. if you really go through all users one by one or if you use some sort of filter methods.

### The real problem

The real problem is the "notification" part. Scalability is more crucial here because you want to be done sending all notifications in a timely manner. I would :

- outsource the part of "sending" a notification into a seperate API and
- include a Queue Functioniality with option on Batch Processing

Comment: Thank you! Can you please attach a link for Batch Processing?

Comment: Some big names used in the industry of queuing are probably Apache Kafka (https://kafka.apache.org/) and RabbitMQ (https://www.rabbitmq.com/) - if you want to test a few prototypes I'd like to use Better-Queue (https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-queue) - but these all leave out the part of scaling. This you need to setup yourself of course so look into Kubernetes & Docker or let Google/Amazon handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is, you should create a separate collection with notification details, with two main keys, "**notification_trigger_date**" and "**user_id**" and a combined index on these 2 keys "**notification_trigger_date_user_id_1**".

```js
"notification_log_collection": {
  "notification_trigger_date": "2020-12-31",
  "user_id": "",
  "extra_info":{
    "any_details_here":{}
  }
  
}
```

Now to get the eligible users in your crontab you simply have to query in the "notification_trigger_date" collection, get the users and send the notification.

Some Advantages of this design:-

1. You will extract only the eligible users from the DB.
2. You can keep the logs corresponding to that notification.
3. Add a TTL in this collection, which might be "notification_trigger_date + 15 days"
4. Scalable to any number of users be it 1M, or 10M

One thing to note here is that you have to delete and create a new document in this collection if the "interval" key is changed by the user input.

you might consider keeping the barder_id in the above collection, that is your choice.

"FAN OUT" The concept here is to take the processing at the write time and make your DB get calls simple.