# Create daily tasks in MERN project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mern

I'm working on this MERN todo application. I want to create tasks and daily tasks.
Daily tasks are going to be everyday, or maybe once a week.
I have no idea how can I count time till the next day when
I have to show the task on the front-end.

The only idea I have is to make 2 different mongoose models: Task, DailyTask
and do something... Still, I can't understand how to set timer till the time,
when I have to show the task.

What kind of approach do you think I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

So how exactly do you have something running in the background that will remind the user when the task is due?

Answer: Assuming that this todo app will be on the cloud and used by many users, you can run a cron task to fetch each user's notes and see if the due date has been reached, and then save a notification for the user to see.

Answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65468824/6535167

Answer (score 0):

A suitable approach may be to use the task scheduler module `node-cron`.

```
npm install node-cron
```

To use:

---

```
const cron = require('node-cron')


//cron.schedule(interval, function);

//Daily task example: execute every day at 5PM
cron.schedule('0 0 17 * * *', yourTask);

//Weekly task example: execute every week on Monday
cron.schedule('* * * * Mon', yourTask);
```

See https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron for more information